# VSCode + remote dev + django: avoiding forwarding ports

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm using VSCode remote development to run and debug a django project inside a Docker container. In my `devcontainer.json` I forwarded the port 8000

```
 "forwardPorts": [8000],
```

and this is my `launch.json`

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/myapp/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "0.0.0.0:8000"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

When I start the debug with such a configuration, I see 4 ports forwarded: port 8000 and other 3 random high ports

```
8000 -> localhost:8000 (the only one I'd expect to see)
34075 -> 127.0.0.1:34075
37301 -> 127.0.0.1:37301
42129 -> 127.0.0.1:42129
```

I'm wondering why those three ports are forwarded and how I can avoid it.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing... I end up with hundreds of open ports due to debugging.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4243#issuecomment-754079334) are some hints to avoid forwarding ports. I guess they will be opened anyhow into the dev container, though.

Answer (score 5):

*This is caused by the **automatic port mapping behaviour** of the ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers.*
*See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_publishing-a-port*

> **Publishing a port**
>
> Docker has the concept of "publishing" ports when the blah blah blah
>
> To publish a port, you can:
>
> Use the appPort property: blah blah

*"appPort" property must be in **devcontainer.json***

```
  "appPort": [ 3000, "8921:5000" ]
```

> Use the Docker Compose ports mapping:
> Blah Blah

*They say that the "appPort" property is going to be mapped like we do on the docker-compose file. If you are running it with docker-compose file maybe the next code is also a solution. If you are not planning to use docker-compose then **setting "appPort" property in devcontainer.json should be enough to avoid automatic mapping.***

```
  ports:
  - "3000"
  - "8921:5000"
```

*Then **F1** to open dialog, **rebuild** devcontainer and **happy hacking**!*

Comment: This is a good answer for a new contributor!

Comment: Ty JAY, I'm sure using appPort that way avoids the 3 random ports opened by devcontainer. I liked devcontainers too much.